A subspace $E$ of a inner product space (not Hilbert) $X$ is closed iff $E=(E^\perp)^\perp.$ Not asking for an example. Trying to prove it.
I am trying to prove $E$ is closed iff $E=(E^\perp)^\perp.$
Forward direction: Assume $E$ is closed, i.e. by definition, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\} \in E$ such that it converges to a point let $x \in X,$ which is also in $E.$
Now, from the definition of an orthogonal component, it is clear that $E\subset (E^\perp)^\perp.$
To prove $ (E^\perp)^\perp \subset E, $ I am assuming first $x \notin E, but \in (E^\perp)^\perp.$ i.e.,
$$\langle x,y\rangle =0 , \quad \forall y \in E^\perp$$
Thus, the vector $x$ has a non-zero projection onto $E^\perp,$ i.e. there exists one such $ y \in E^\perp$ s.t. $\langle x,y \rangle \ne 0.$ Which is a contradiction to our assumption $x \in (E^\perp)^\perp.$
Hence $x$ must be in $E.$ Thus, $ (E^\perp)^\perp \subset E. $
Finally, $(E^\perp)^\perp = E.$
Backward Direction: From the definition of orthogonal component $(E^\perp)^\perp.$ Thus, $(E^\perp)^\perp = E,$ implies $E$ closed.
I don't know whether the forward direction is rigorous enough. (If $X$ was Hilbert, then the Hilbert projection theorem straightforward gives us the proof.)

The forward direction is false, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4978204/465145

It's a proof , the similar question is asking for a counter example.

I mean, the question has a counterexample, so the proof is wrong and the question just have a negative answer.

Also, where in your proof of the forward direction did you use the fact that $E$ is closed?

Okay, let's say I am wrong in both approaches (forward). Which I know I am. Is it possible for anyone to guide me in the right direction?

@FunnyGuy There is no right direction, the proposition you’re trying to prove is just false, as the counterexample demonstrates. You do know what counterexamples mean, right?

@DavidGao I talked with my professor, and she said it is not false.

@FunnyGuy Regardless of what your professor said, it is false, in that direction at least, and David's linked answer proves this. There is no proof of this assertion. Now, we could find issues with your proof, or help you prove the converse direction, but we can't prove a false statement true!

@TheoBendit that would be helpful!! Thank you!

Let's start with a proof of the backwards direction. It suffices to show that $F^\perp$ is closed for any subspace $F$, as this implies $(E^\perp)^\perp$ is closed.
We write:
\begin{align*}
F^\perp &= \{x \in X : \forall f \in F, \langle x, f \rangle = 0\} \\
&= \bigcap_{f \in F} \{x \in X : \langle x, f \rangle = 0\}.
\end{align*}
Note that $\{x \in X : \langle x, f \rangle = 0\}$ is the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$ under the continuous map $x \mapsto \langle x, f \rangle$, and so by continuity, the set must be closed. This makes $F^\perp$ the intersection of closed sets, which itself must be closed.

As for your forward direction, I'm with you until:

Thus, the vector $x$ has a non-zero projection onto $E^\perp$

It is true, in Hilbert spaces, that vectors admit projections onto closed subspaces. In general inner product spaces, not so much. See here.

I was trying to say that if $x \notin E$, then it can not be orthogonal to any element $y\in E^\perp$. Implying $\langle x,y\rangle \ne 0.$ Is this wrong?

@FunnyGuy That is wrong. Just read the example I linked to. $E^\perp$ can literally be just ${0}$.

@DavidGao in your example you are in $l^2$ right? I mean your space is $l^2.$ Correct me if I am wrong. I am trying to understand this.

@FunnyGuy No. The space is $c_{00}$. It’s the subspace of $\ell^2$ consisting of only finitely supported sequences.
